# How to do a meta description for seo optimisation

Tags: html

I am trying to include meta tags for each of my main and non main page and so far got a few done but when I tried to search for my terms on google, it doesn't appear...

I have included some meta tags in the header section

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
            <meta name="description" content="The number 1 piano website for learning how to play the piano">
            <meta name="keywords" content="piano lessons, bastien piano series, pianocourse101, the best piano lessons on the internet, learn how to play the piano right from your own home, how to play the piano, piano lessons for children, bastien piano basics">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen,projection,tv">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico">


<title>Welcome to PianoCourse101: The most comprehensive piano lessons on the internet!</title>

<div clas="main-section">

  <header>
```

Comment: Google and other search engines no longer use the `keyword` meta tag.  Use the `title` and `description` meta tags.  Also , just because you add meta tags does not mean you are instantly going to be at the top of Google's queries.  Link from Google about this here https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO is a big topic. Here's your answer:

`< meta name="description" content="SEO is (not) fun!" />`

However, this is more of a first step and dead end in SEO. You need to establish credibility and be linked to from other credible sites. This has nothing to do with a few HTML tags. You will not suddenly get first page on google from mapping your site and adding a few HTML tags. Good (read: effective) SEO takes months and sometimes years of sitting around and telling people to go to your site. This is not a magic solution. *Eventually*, with persistence and patience, you will get ranked higher. Just keep in mind that while SEO isn't worthless, it definitely isn't magic.

Comment: That explains why my website is not at the top of google yet if I don't get traffic

Comment: @piano0011 it takes a while. Keep researching and stay up to date on what matters and what doesn't. You also may want to consider paid ads if your website is profitable.